# Union view (query) between SQL Server and Oracle tables

Tags: sql-server, oracle, union

I have 2 tables, one is in SQL Server, the other is in Oracle (this is driven by the software that feeds the databases and cannot be changed).

Currently I am using MS Access and have pulled both of these tables in as 'linked tables'. MS Access makes it very easy to pull in data from a variety of different data sources (Oracle, SQL Server, XML, Excel etc.) and then query as if the tables were in the same environment.

I want to have the same view in SQL Server. Is this possible?

The reason I want this is because as it stands, for anyone to use my MS Access query, they need the ODBC connections on their local workstations. Many of the workstations do not have the Oracle driver installed.

I want to push the ODBC requirement to a server and then just use a SQL Server view in the MS Access database and remove the linked tables. Every workstation has a SQL driver which would make this much easier for me.

```
**SQL Server**  **ORACLE**
TABLE_A         TABLE_B

Name            Name
Description     Description
VALUE1          VALUE1
STATUS          STATUS
```

Union query in MS Access is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM TABLE_A

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM TABLE_B;
```

I want a view in SQL Server that replicates this `Union` query.

Comment: Your current Access union query should work in SQL Server (I think).  Have you tried using it yet?

Comment: Careful. As this query uses `UNION`, not `UNION ALL`, the `DISTINCT`s are technically unnecessary (all of the results will get an implicit `DISTINCT`), but also, because of that requirement to sort and de-duplicate the results, the query may end up very inefficient when pulling in data from linked sources. (Also, `SELECT *` is always a bad idea, but especially so when selecting in a `UNION` from multiple sources that need not agree on the type and order of columns.) As convenient as this might be, it won't scale well on large tables.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen Mostert, both tables have approximately 400,000 rows each.  I'm not trying to do anything more complicated than return all distinct values from each table so I take your point, but scaling is not going to be problematic in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a "linked server" on SQL Serwer to Oracle database.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4396/creating-a-sql-server-2014-linked-server-for-an-oracle-11g-database/

Then you will use a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM TABLE_A

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Oracle_link_server..schema.table_b;
```